# BouncyCastle PGP textmode in Java implementation does not convert to CR/LF

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

Is there any way to specify the textmode in BouncyCastle PGP encryption Java implementation?

I tried this but no luck (encrypted with UNIX line ending and decrypted in Windows):

```
PGPLiteralDataGenerator pgpldg = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator(false);
OutputStream ldout = pgpldg.open(compout, PGPLiteralData.TEXT, name, data.length, PGPLiteralData.NOW);
```

Comment: Is the text mode bit set (`gpg --list-packets`)? Is the behavior different if you use GnuPG on the command line (`gpg --textmode --encrypt`)?

Comment: Yea, I tried GnuPG . I did encrypt a file with '**LF**' with text mode and decrypted in Windows. The file has '**CRLF**' as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 5.9.  Literal Data Packet (Tag 11)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.9) defines that in text mode, data should be encoded with `<CR><LF>` line endings:

> Text data is stored with  text endings (i.e., network-
> normal line endings).  These should be converted to native line
> endings by the receiving software.

GnuPG is doing so (`--compress-algo 0` disables compression, `--store` just wraps the input in a literal data packet):

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gpg2 --textmode --compress-algo 0 --store | hexdump -c
0000000   � 020   t  \0   X  \b   �   u   f   o   o  \r  \n   b   a   r
0000010  \r  \n                                                        
0000012
```

Reading through [BouncyCastle's source code for `PGPLiteralDataGenerator`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPLiteralDataGenerator.java) and other called classes, I cannot find a single trace BouncyCastle is doing this (required) conversion. All I can find is that they write the encoding into the header (`t`, `u` or `b`). This is a BouncyCastle bug. They might fix it if you report it, otherwise (or until then), you have to add the carriage return on your own.